# Need File.isAbsolute() for platform independent application working with UNIX file system

Tags: java, file

my Java application can run on all platforms. It is working with some remote files located on FTP server on Linux. To navigate on the FTP I use absolute paths like `/home/user`. If I create a `File` like:

```
File f = new File("/home/user");
```

Then the result of calling:

```
f.isAbsolute();
```

seems to be platform dependent. But since I work always with remote UNIX like filesystem I want to get always `true` in this case. Is there any built-in java way how to identify if file is absolute on unix platform?

Of course I can write a helper method and see if the file name `.startsWith("/")` but I was looking for some built-in java solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is there any built-in java way how to identify if file is absolute on unix platform?**

No, there is no "*would be absolute on a UNIX platform*"-method in the standard API.

According to the documentation for `File` though, doing `.startsWith("/")` would correspond to the implementation of `File.isAbsolute` on a UNIX platforms:

> [...] *On UNIX systems, a pathname is absolute if its prefix is "/".* [...]

So that's probably the solution I would have gone for in this case.

Comment: Understand this and will go with this solution probably but from the File javadoc: "User interfaces and operating systems use system-dependent pathname strings to name files and directories. This class presents an abstract, system-independent view of hierarchical pathnames." If File is system independent why it's isAbsolute method system dependent?

Comment: That's a very good question. To be honest I'd actually consider filing a documentation-bug-report on that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps with your problem but also from the [File API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) you can use methods to distinguish the paths to file.

```
 File   getAbsoluteFile()
      Returns the absolute form of this abstract pathname.
 String     getAbsolutePath()
      Returns the absolute pathname string of this abstract pathname.
 File   getCanonicalFile()
      Returns the canonical form of this abstract pathname.
 String     getCanonicalPath() 
      Returns the canonical pathname string of this abstract pathname.
```

Comment: The implementations of those methods is system dependent. Also `getCanonicalFile()` only really works completely if the file indicated by the pathname exists on the local system.